# How to upload multiple files(picking mutliple files at once) using JSF1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2

How to pick multiple  files at once using  JSF 1.2.
I am able to upload multiple files using rich faces(only one file selection at once), but can't pick multiple files at once. Prime faces provides support for multi file upload but to work with Prime Faces, JSF2.x version is required. We are stick to JSF 1.2.

In rich faces **`<rich:fileUpload/>`** tag has an attribute **`allowFlash`**, if we make this value as true it allows us to select multiple files, but after selecting multiple files its throwing an error saying

> ContentTypeList does not contain a supported content type: text/*

After throwing error, even the upload button dissapears

Even I referred few other libraries like blue imp jquery multi file upload but I have zero knowledge on jquery and I don't find any example related to JSF1.x file upload.
Can anybody knows the solution?.

Comment: @BalusC you are the right person to ask. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If your application runs on a JavaEE 6 application server or on a (with JSF 2.x configured) servlet container, take a look at [Primefaces file upload component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/multiple.xhtml). It supports multiple file selection for a modern browsers. You could set file pattern to be accepted only *.zip files from browser's file selection dialog, using:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.listenerMethod}" mode="advanced" multiple="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(zip)$/" />
```

For a legacy JSF 1.2 environment you could use Primefaces <= 2.1 or as mentioned @VasilLukach [RichFaces 3.3.3 file upload component](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf?c=fileUpload&tab=usage). Both of them support only single file selection (in order to upload several files, user have to click on a file selection button several times).

See more examples and/or documentation in linked showcases above.

Regardless of the used component library, your use case mentioned in comment:

> I need to select all the three zip files from browser , then extract individual zip files and upload them into server

seems to be wrong. Usually user choose one or several files to be uploaded and then they are processed after transmission by your application on the server-side (unzip, persist or whatever else).

Comment: I just gone through the above link, on the first glimpse I just saw multiple file upload(individual files), but I don't find anything related to multi zip files(individual Zip Files) upload.

Comment: Zip files from the browser's or backend's perspective are just files. You can change file pattern `<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="..." mode="advanced" multiple="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(zip)$/" />` to allow only *.zip files to be selected from browser. What is your use case?

Comment: @olexd Are you sure it will work with JSF 1.2? Maybe old RichFaces 3.3.4 is better alternative.

Comment: FileUpload example in RichFaces 3.3.3 is [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf;jsessionid=0B32422D9C72A223EE25DBB7DDAC63E7?c=fileUpload&tab=usage)

Comment: @olexd Jquery supports mutli file selection. Is it possible to work with jquery in jSF1.2 environment?

Comment: @MohanraoKolisetti, Surely, JSF is a server-side framework, whereas JQuery is a client-side javascript library. You can use JQuery or any other javascript library as a front-end or even build your own JSF custom components which will render an HTML-code with third-party javascript-snippets. Primefaces is a good example to demonstrate this - it leverages JQuery and some its widgets.